# mysql field in table

Tags: mysql, field, addition

```
SELECT * FROM users
SELECT * FROM country
```

The `users` and `country` tables have the same field called "City".
The table `country` have a field "Prov".

I need to add a field "Prov" in users table.

Comment: what you want i cant understand

Comment: In table users there is not "Prov" field. The "prov" field is in t Country table. I suggest in table users and Country table thers is the SAME field "City". I need to load the"Prov" exactly correspond a City Field in the users Table

Select  City from Users
Select City, Prov From Country

Answer (score 0):

```
Select u.city,c.prov
from users u
join country c on u.city = c.city;
```

Comment: Solved:

SELECT * from  Country
INNER JOIN  users
on users.City=Country.City